# Usage of "find" linux command

Tags: linux, find

My question is about linux commands. I need to find all ".sh" files and I need to delete all the files which end with ".sh" extension automatically. Could anyone please help me out by giving suitable linux command for it?

Comment: Have you tried reading `man find`? It gives you all the information you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sh
find . -type f -name '*.sh' -exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: this is the right way and perfect to delete all the files automatically....thank you